# How to get Sonarlint CLI output in JSON/XML format

Tags: command-line-interface, sonarlint

Currently we are using Sonar-lint CLI for local environment code analysis and It is generating output in html format, But I want it in JSON/XML format so I can easily parse it and do further procedure.

Please let me know if any one having any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

The only outputs possible with SonarLint CLI are a HTML report and a Console report.
For more advance usages and tracking of issues in projects, it's better to use a Scanner to have the results in a SonarQube server.

Comment: Is there any provision in next version of Sonar-lint CLI for getting output in JSON/XML format instead of HTML report